# Want to add commas and in last Dot or blank

Tags: wordpress

For a loop in Wordpress I want to output a list with places, separated with a comma and ending with a point.

Like this:

```
Canada, USA, England, Pakistan
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$values = get_field('job_qualification', $post->post_parent, true);

if( $values ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $values as $value ): ?>
    <?php echo $value; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
global $post;
$values = get_field('job_qualification', $post->post_parent, true);
if( $values )
{
    echo implode(", ", $values).".";
}
```

Comment: I try to implement but not working, can you provide me the full code may b I am doing something wrong.

Comment: That was the full code :). To debug, dump the `$values` and see whether or not you get the actual values. If the `$value` is set and it contains the required vales, then the code should work.

Comment: Sorry I was doing a mistake and really thanks for this but can you guide me here that how to trim the text like I want to show only this..

(Canada, USA...)